# How to associate more than one file extension with a given mode in `use-package`

Tags: major-mode, use-package

When using `use-package`, is there a way to associate more than one file extension with a particular mode in one place instead of multiple locations?

Case in point is that I would like to associate both `js` and `jsx` files with js2-mode. Currently what I have is:

```
(use-package js2-mode
  :mode "\\.js\\'"
  :init
  (setq js2-highlight-level 3) 
  (add-hook 'js2-mode-hook (lambda () (auto-revert-mode)
                                      (setq auto-revert-interval 0.1)))
  :ensure t)

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.jsx\\'" . js2-mode))
```

... which I don't like as the extensions are specified in two different places.

Comment: Couldn't you just turn your regexp in to `\\.jsx?\\'` to account for both filenames?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
:mode "\\.jsx?\\'"
```

Remember: all those backslashes are there because it's a regexp, so you really want to take advantage of it when you can, otherwise you're just suffering through those backslashes for nothing.

You could also write it

```
:mode "\\.\\(js\\|jsx\\)\\'"
```

or many other ways, of course.

Answer (score 15):

The following should work:

```lisp
(use-package js2-mode
  :mode (("\\.js\\'" . js2-mode)
         ("\\.jsx\\'" . js2-mode))
  ...
  :ensure t)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to scatotonic's way you can use this shorter equivalent expression:

```lisp
(use-package js2-mode
  :mode
  "\\.js\\'"
  "\\.jsx\\'")
```

It's not as useful when only doing the two entries, (especially since they can be merged with the regex `"\\.jsx?\\'"`), yet it's really helpful for more generic stuff like `web-mode`.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty dang flexible...  This works, and is my preferred method when the mode name is the same as the package name:

```lisp
(use-package js2-mode
  :mode ("\\.js\\'"
         "\\.jsx\\'"))
```

I do see why a regex like in [Stephan's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/21201/2070) would be nice for the js/jsx case.  Here's an example where a single regex may be too complicated and a list of regexs may be preferred:

```lisp
(use-package groovy-mode
  :mode ("\\.groovy\\'"
         "^Jenkinsfile$"))
```

[scatotonic's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/21192/2070) would be my choice if the mode name is different from the package name.